# How to log response body from client by overriding ExchangeFilterFunction ofResponseProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a requirement to log the response (Readable format) in WebClient Configuration class.

```
@Bean
WebClient webClient() {
     return WebClient.builder().filter(this.logRequest()).filter(this.logResponse()).filter(this.metricsLoggingFilterFunction()).build();
}

private ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
     return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
          String statusCode = clientResponse.statusCode().toString();

        ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeClass> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeClass>() {
        };
        clientResponse.bodyToMono(responseType).subscribe(i -> {
            String responsePayLoad = new Gson().toJson(i);
            System.out.println("**********response-payload3:"+responsePayLoad);
        });
          return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    });
}
```

I am able to print the response in ofResponseProcessor but it is not working on my service class. If I try to subscribe to the same clientResponse twice - I am getting the error message "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed."

I saw few solutions with cache() and share() but I was not able to make it work. How to subscribe multiple times?

Comment: I think you need to extract the body so `clientRespoinse.body()` should fix it

Comment: There is no body() method.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following version:

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
  return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response ->
    Mono.just(
       response.mutate()
          .body(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.map(dataBuffer1 -> {
             System.out.println("**********response-payload3:"+ dataBuffer1.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
             return dataBuffer1;
           }))
           .build()));
```